# Difference between self and super

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, inheritance

just had a noob question. I'm trying to understand the difference between calling self and super. Now I understand inheritance and other fundamental OOP concepts, but the idea of self and super is still not clear to me. I'll illustrate my question with an example.

So the the below code performs a segue when the phone is tilted upside-down. I understand that "Scene2ViewController" is a subclass of "UIViewController" and so "Scene2ViewController" inherits all of UIViewController's methods. And so below I'm calling the method performSegueWithIdentifier with the receiver of the message being self. Now when I change "self" to "super" the code still executes the same way. Isn't calling super the same as calling self? If someone could explain this to me it would be appreciated, thanks.

```
//Scene2ViewController.m
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToScene1" sender:self];
}

return (interfaceOrientation == 
        UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` and `super` actually both point to the same object. `super` is a keyword that tells the compiler to generate instructions that start the search for a method definition in the super class rather than in the current class.

```
@interface A : NSObject {}
- (void)foo;
@end

@implementation A
- (void)foo {
    NSLog(@"A's foo!");
}
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void)foo {
    NSLog(@"B's foo!");
}
@end

//...somewhere in a method of class B...
[self foo];    // prints "B's foo" in the console
[super foo];    // prints "A's foo" in the console
```

If we assume, per the comment, that the last lines are somewhere in a method of B, then `self` points to some instance of B. `super` also points to that same instance of B. But when you use `self` to call `foo`, the search for an implementation of `foo` starts with class B. When you use `super`, the search for a `foo` starts with B's superclass, A.

`super` is especially handy when you want to preserve the inherited behavior, but add something on. So, we could have B's implementation of `foo` call A's version using `[super foo]`. Without `super` there'd be no way to call the inherited method, and calling `foo` from the overridden method would result in infinite recursion.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to call the super of a super? For example if there were a ClassC (subclass of B), and ClassC wanted to call foo of classA instead of foo of ClassB.

Comment: No. Unless you want to start playing games with the runtime, there's no facility for that. I think most people would agree that if you have a need for that, there's probably something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 5):

When you call a method of `self` (or rather send a message to `self` in Objective-C terms) the runtime will search for an implementation of that method in the inheritance hierarchy, starting with `self`, going up to `NSObject`. So if `self` implemented that method, it will be executed. If not, the `super` class will be checked and so on.

Sending the message to `super` is very similar, with the exception that the runtime will start looking for an implementation in `super` and skip `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Well sometimes, in a subclass, you might override a function that was already defined in the parent class.  Frequently this happens in the init function.  So if you need to call the parent class's init function you call super. If you need the subclass' function you call self.  If only the parent has the function declared then Self and super act the same.  But if only the subclass has the declaration then you cannot call the function from super.